# Does Picasa allow hotlinking?

Tags: picasa-web-albums, terms-of-service

Does Picasa Web Albums allow you to hotlink the images on other websites? Or will doing so violate their terms of service?

I tried to find this information in their terms but could not find it and would like clarification.

Answer (score 3):

They readily give you links to embed images in web pages, so assume it's ok.